# Error handling importing json to mongo

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a json file which looks like this:

```
        {"_id":"id1","cat":["C","D","R","P"],"desc":"some desc","name":"some_name","category":"categ","languages":["en"],"type":"swf","start_date":1.39958850681748E9},

    {"_id":"toy-driver","cat":["C","D","R","P"],"desc":"some desc","name":"name2","category":"Rac","languages":["en"],"type":"swf","start_date":1.399588506820609E9},
............
```

It consists of about 900 rows. When i happen to import 2 or 3 similar rows using the command:

```
mongoimport -d test -c test --jsonArray file.json
```

it imports perfectly without any errors whereas importing the entire file causes some error.

```
imported 0 objects
encountered 1 error
```

Comment: Does it tell you what the error is? Double check that all of the json is well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, there are 2 problems here.

1. `--jsonArray` expects 1 JSON document where all of your 900 records are part of a single array.
   You're supplying 900 standalone JSON rows from within a file, which doesn't answer the --jsonArray format. (also, drop the comma at the end of each line, mongoimport expects newlines.
2. if you want to import data from a file, you have to specify the keyword `--file file.json`

I believe that if you'll remove the --jsonArray argument and add the --file keyword, this will be fine. e.g.:

```
mongoimport -d test -c test --file file.json
```

Where file.json is similar to this:

```
{"_id":"id1","cat":["C","D","R"], ... "type":"swf","start_date":1.39958850681748E9}
{"_id":"id2","cat":["C","D","R"], ... "type":"swf","start_date":1.39958850681748E9}
{"_id":"id3","cat":["C","D","R"], ... "type":"swf","start_date":1.39958850681748E9}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: One more thing, consider chaging the type of the start_date, to a string or long representing a epoch unix timestamp (e.g. 1408190446)

Comment: Well the command with jsonArray works fine, there was a text-wrapping issue with the text editor i was using. I chose brackets(text editor) to resolve the issue. It works fine now!Thanks anyway :)